# Pro Tools 11 here already?

Tags: pro-tools

I literally JUST got PT10. Doh! Looks like 64 bit is the big change. Anyone considering making the switch?

[link text](http://apps.avid.com/protools11/)

Answer (score 2):

No rush - ProTools vX.0 is always buggy/semi stable....

and this sucks:
apparently PT11 is only stereo, if you want multichannel you have to upgrade to PT11HD
and there is no COMPLETE Toolkit anymore... & cost of CPTK to 11HD upgrade is 999$!?!

Comment: If that happens it's a really unfortunate choice by Avid. Features which are clearly zero cost to develop or implement being sold at inflated prices is not cool. Deciding to restrict software feels deeply counter-intuitive, especially when it's not even that cheap. 

Comment: @tim to clarify it further, these 10/CPTK users are being offer a software-only version of HD at $999 - Avid otherwise still ties HD to hardware purchases.  So for those of us who haven't had the chance to get CPTK or are stuck on DVTK still), you gotta trade up or buy an HD Native or higher to get these features - so for someone like myself, still on 8.0.6 with DVTK, you're talking $3,999 minimum.

Comment: If the multichannel thing is the only thing you need HD for and the other CPTK features are rolled into PT 11, that may be okay - I can live without surround for now.  But everything so far is indicative that all of the CPTK features (multi video tracks, extended edit functions, etc) are going only to HD now.

Comment: session caching and VCAs are part of the CPTK that will be disappearing. there's a lot of under the hood stuff that gets lost.

Comment: their new 'upgrade path' basically kills freelancers working at home (for bigger studios)  in surround with a decent featureset. 
it is a shame and avid is really pushing their luck on this strategy. most likely they're running on empty and pushed out 11 in advance to please shareholders, releasing a buggy rework with a lot of marketing BS.. and at the same time make users steer away from investing in their products. i have a 2nd hand cptk and that won't be applicable for the upgrade to 11HD because it's already registered. so I'm left out here with PT10+cptk until i can afford a HD set :(

Comment: (oh btw i was aware of not being eligible to upgrade when i bought the cptk, so i've no right to complain. avid eliminating cptk however is a shame.)

Comment: losing the ability to have multiple video files in one session would truly suck! Who doesn't work in a super session these days, with all reels in one session?

Comment: I think you can still have multiple videos, Tim...just not multiple video TRACKS.

Comment: and video TRACKS is what we need (reconform etc), especially these days.

Comment: From what I got out of the Avid rep at NAB, you can still have multiple video tracks, you cannot have multiple video tracks online at the same time.

Comment: but it never was possible to have multiple tracks online or am i mistaking cptk with hd features..? anyway, let's hope 11 will run stable :)

Comment: not multiple tracks, multiple Quicktime files eg Reel 1 at 01.00.00.00, R2 at 02.00.00.00, R3 at 03.00.00.00....

Comment: this just out; video editing and multiple tracks only on 11HD. http://www.pro-tools-expert.com/home-page/2013/4/15/pro-tools-11-v-pro-tools-11-hd-the-differences-in-a-chart.html
no word yet on multiple videos on 1 track.

Answer (score 2):

S.H.A.F.T.E.D. For those of us who own Pro Tools and the CPTK 2, we now have to spend a huge amount of money AGAIN to re-purchase the features we have already paid $2000 for. Ludicrous. Not only that, it's also 40% more for our upgrade than anyone else will be paying, just to keep the same feature set. The reason we bought the CPTK 2 is because we can't afford to spring for the high end HD set-up's like the big facilities so the vastly higher upgrade price for all of us freelance/home based Pro Tools users seems really unfair. I would happily pay the $599 for the HD upgrade seeing as that is essentially the system we are upgrading from but to add another $400 on top of that just seems a bit greedy. Anyone from Avid care to comment?

Comment:   
 I think I once heard that Avid was a company only interested in making the most money out of their pro customers that they've hooked to use their systems, eventhough there are plenty of very professional contenders (e.g. Nuendo).

Answer (score 1):

The strap line of Avid's own [press release](http://www.avid.com/US/press-room/Avid-Pro-Tools-11-Sets-New-Standard-for-Audio-Production) is "Sets New Standard for Audio Production".  I don't mean to sound cynical, but reading the feature list there is nothing new here that is not already available from other vendors.  Even when it comes to the supposed performance increase they are very vague, stating "Delivers multiple times the processing power of Pro Tools 10 on the same hardware configurations."  What is the multiple? x1.1? x1.2? x1.3? etc.  Has anyone seen any precise performance figures?

Given the cost of upgrading again (less than 8 months since we upgraded to 10) we will be looking at alternative vendors.

Comment: Take this with a grain of salt, but I read that people who tested it say that the performance increase isn't that impressive at all... 

Comment: @Asimov my reading of such vagary was that it can't be a very substantial improvement.  I look forward to actually seeing some real figures.    

Comment: Got some figures here: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BHbJKDmCIAAzlVJ.jpg

Comment: @Internet  ha ha.....that is a good one  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

While I understand some of the complaints about pricing, I think it is important to keep in mind that this is a huge upgrade -- potentially the biggest one ever. Contrary to popular belief, 64-bit is not the biggest change; among other things, Avid completely rewrote the entire audio engine (goodbye DAE) and finally ditched QuickTime in favor of the new Avid Video Engine. Add to that new features such as dynamic host processing (which can save a lot of resources especially with checkerboarding) and offline bouncing (which, granted, most DAWs have had for years), and you realize that we're essentially looking at a completely different Pro Tools under the hood. I can't even begin to imagine how much that cost in R&D.

Comment: ofcourse it's a rebuilt from ground up, but rebuilding all your client relations is probably not what they are looking for. i for one am doubting an upgrade. nuendo seems more and more attractive these days...

Comment: wait this video has a better view on the subject: Pt 11 - 'next level shit'
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rdOSPtOnvmo

Comment: @Arnoud: I am not defending Avid's choice to discontinue CTPK, which, like the rest of you, I disagree with. I was merely pointing out the scale of the upgrade and that in some cases (again, not CTPK) it warrants the increased prices.
As to the video you posted: the NAB demo was actually quite a bit more informative. I believe it's somewhere online on youtube now.

Comment: Hi Alex, ofcourse it's a big upgrade (albeit a late one). And paying for software always seems to hurt a bit more than hardware upgrades, so complaint are numerous. But it really feels a bit 'evil' (to use a big word) to launch a new version after only 1 or 2 years, especially when you take in account that avid stock has been plummeting for a few years now. It feels like a wrong move, scaring away older customers (after years of HD purchases or cptk upgrades). That's mostly where all the annoyance is coming from I think.

Comment: edit: correction it's 2+ years after pt10.

Comment: this is the video you're talking about? https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=VEWdhm3iUVk#

Comment: Yes, that's the one. Still a bit scarce on overall feature list, but it gives a good overview of some of the bigger improvements.